# Flatten a GIT master branch

Tags: git

I have a GIT repository on which a merge remained separated from the main branch.
How can I flatten this case ? :

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rebase the sequence `dde3dc3`, `7d258ff`, `838a941` .. `00565b3` on top of `dfc22c8`. This can be done by using the `--onto` argument to `git rebase` (untested):

```
$ git rebase --onto dfc22c8 00e3cd7 00565b3
```